# Experiencing issues using DBMS_CLOUD.GET_OBJECT in oracle cloud infrastructure Autonomous Database serverless

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to create a DB Link between 2 Autonomous databases (Serverless) in OCI

List of steps i followed

1. I created the necessary credentials for the user using dbms_cloud.create_credential
2. Now, i try to upload the Wallet file (which i have stored in Object storage) using "dbms_cloud.get_object". It produces the following error

   ORA-20000: ORA-29283: invalid file operation: nonexistent file or path [29434]
   ORA-06512: at "C##CLOUD$SERVICE.DBMS_CLOUD", line 983
   ORA-06512: at "C##CLOUD$SERVICE.DBMS_CLOUD", line 2622
   ORA-06512: at line 2

If i use the wrong credential or if i change the uri, the error that the system produces are different. I believe oracle is able to get to the object, yet it produces this error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

DBMS_CLOUD.GET_OBJECT supports ability to read data from an object store file and return the contents as a BLOB, or save the contents to a file in the given directory object in your Autonomous Database.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/dbms-cloud-subprograms.html#GUID-3DB888C9-18C7-4A26-8DA8-EDFB260E2B14

It seems that you are trying to download a Wallet file to directory object for creating a database link. Autonomous Database automatically provisions a database file system to store files. Although the exact SQL syntax is not posted, but the error indicates that the syntax is correct. The error appears like the database file system is not accessible, and it is an internal error for the service.

You could workaround the issue by restarting the Autonomous Database. As this is an old question, the issue could be automatically addressed by now with automatic maintenance of Autonomous Database.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, what region are you experiencing this in? Free tier or paid?

Ultimately, there is nothing wrong with your syntax used or a wrong usage. Unfortunately the issue you're experiencing is likely an internal error/bug, and can be fixed by OCI ops. I highly recommend submitting a service request.

If you have not submitted one in the past, you can read up on how to here - https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/GSG/Tasks/contactingsupport.htm#3Openasupportservicerequest